# What does viewContainer option do to a DojoX Calendar?

Tags: calendar, dojo

I have Calendar contained in a `<div id="calendardiv">` with relative positioning, so that the calendar wouldn't overlap the main menu of my app. What's the functionality of `viewContainer` parameter? The [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/) just says that it contains the view of your calendar. What's that supposed to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in the doc, this returns a `domNode`. As there nothing more said about it, it seems to me as if this was a "placeholder-`domNode`" created to store the `views` which could get displayed in your `calendar` widget.

There is another `domNode`-property in every `widget` which contains the actual appearing representation of the widget. It seems to me as if the widget pics views from the `viewContainer` and builds the required representation from the ones they need... You may just test it by printing it out at runtime and checking for its id or sth. in the parsed sourcecode of the page... There you can see what it contains anyway..